# How to tell which dynamic control sent to an event?

Tags: vba, excel

This is my first attempt at working with dynamically created controls in a user form.  The reason is there will always be a different amount of rows returned by some processing.

I have created a class object **cControlEvent** with the following code. (I cut out the code not pertaining to the checkbox)

```
Public WithEvents CHK As MSForms.CheckBox


Private Sub CHK_Change()
   ** tell me which box was changed **
End Sub
```

in the code module, I have the following code:

```
Dim CHK_Evts As New Collection 

sub Form_Builder()

**non relevant code deleted****
    Set Evt = New cControlEvent
    If i_Columns = 1 Then
        Set Evt.CHK = ctl
        CHK_Evts.Add Evt
    Else
**  more code**
    End if
end sub
```

What do I need to change/add to be able to get the name of the control that is firing off the change event?

EDITED TO ADD:

I have a series of dynamically created checkboxes and  textboxes on each line of a user form, with a checkbox before each line,  when the checkbox is checked/unchecked, I need to change the backcolor on all the textboxes in that row.  Each control is named by it's type, then row then column like this CHX_1_1 would be a checkbox on row 1 column 1, and TXT_1_5 would be row 1 column 5.  So, if I know what the name of the checkbox is, I have all I need to change the other controls on that row with a simple for-next loop.

Comment: The `CHK` variable hold everything you need to know about the checkbox - add `MsgBox Chk.Name` to your `CHK_Change` code and it will give you the name.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook that did it!!!!   Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am not quite sure if I understand your question correctly. But it seems to me that it boils down to "which FormControl (linked to a particular procedure) caused this sub to run". If that's the case then you should be able to make use of the

```
Application.Caller
```

Here is a short video to demonstrate it's use in a very simple environment:

[image]

Comment: I clarified.  I'm trying to get the information from a dynamically created control on a user form which will be used to change related controls.  I tried application caller and got a type mismatch error. (error 2023)

Comment: CheckBoxes on forms have one event handler for each checkbox. The above example only works because I am able to assign to two controls the same `sub`. Yet, on a forms each control get's its own sub for each event `CheckBox1_Click`, `CheckBox2_Click`, `CheckBox3_Click`, etc. They cannot share one sub. Hence, `Application.Caller` doesn't make much sense here.

Comment: Thanks I didn't know about that.  I'll use this for another project.

Answer (score 0):

Here's hopefully a full solution showing how to get the properties from the check boxes:

Create a blank userform and add a command button to it.

Add this code to the form (note - `CommandButton1_Click` should be updated to the name of the button you added).

```
Public CHK_Evts As New Collection

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim ChkBox As Variant

    For Each ChkBox In CHK_Evts
        MsgBox ChkBox.Position & vbCr & _
                ChkBox.Status
    Next ChkBox

End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Dim tmpCtrl As Control
    Dim cmbEvent As clsControlEvents
    Dim X As Long

    For X = 1 To 10
        Set tmpCtrl = frmNameParser.Controls.Add("Forms.Checkbox.1", "Name" & X)
        With tmpCtrl
            .Left = 6
            .Top = X * 20 + 24
            .Height = 18
            .Width = 150
        End With

        Set cmbEvent = New clsControlEvents
        Set cmbEvent.CHK = tmpCtrl
        CHK_Evts.Add cmbEvent, "Name" & X
    Next X

End Sub
```

Create a class called `clsControlEvents` and add this code:

```
Public WithEvents CHK As MSForms.CheckBox

Public Property Get Position() As String
    Position = CHK.Top
End Property

Public Property Get Status() As String
    Status = CHK.Value
End Property

Private Sub CHK_Click()
    MsgBox CHK.Name
End Sub
```

The two `GET` procedures pass information back to the `CommandButton1_Click` procedure so it can list information about all check boxes on the form (held in the `CHK_EVTS` collection).
The `CHK_Click` procedure gives immediate information about the check box being clicked.

http://www.cpearson.com/excel/classes.aspx